# Marlin move axis issue

Tags: marlin

I have problems with setting up Marlin for my new printer. Each time I rotate the dial, axis move to the same amount. It doesn't matter how much I moved it, to 1mm or to 20 mm (according to screen), axis move to the same really small step. It happens with all of axis. I tried to change step per unit to much higher value and it still does the same. Maybe you have some ideas guys? :)

Comment: Did you check the stepper current? Maybe the stepper tries to move, but doesn't succeed.

Comment: I figured out that problem was in my endstops. I solved it but still almost the same behavior. Already a bit better, but still not fine. I do not even know how to describe this behavior. Axis move but really weird, direction is correct but amount is wrong and quite random. I'll try to check current as a next step :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update. Jumpers were inserted to 1/16, but stepper chip I have (9488) could not handle that many micro steps. I changed it to 1/8 and now it works good.